# fireTableDataChanged em AbstractTreeTableModel pacote Swingx

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Estou com duvida de como fazer um reload nos objetos de uma `JXTreeTable` utilizando um `Model` > `AbstractTreeTableModel`.

O `AbstractTableModel` de uma `JTable` normal tem o `fireTableDataChanged`, mas como eu faço isso em `AbstractTreeTableModel`?

Pacote: `import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;`

Não sei nem como começar, quem tiver algum material ou uma dica, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, não me recordo muito bem a fonte da solução mas utilizei o `modelSupport` que vem dentro do `AbstractTreeTableModel` ele contem a função `fireNewRoot` que da um reload no root da JXTreeTable assim como o `fireTableDataChanged` do JTable.